# How can i iterate or get all object out of array with object key in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, chart.js

I am working on making a graph in Chart.js, my problem is that i have and array with objects that look like this 
`0:
{y: 17854.69, y2: 14283.75, x: Thu Aug 17 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)}
1:
{y: 41750.08, y2: 33400.06, x: Wed Aug 16 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)}`

my graph have two y axes with different data and a x axes with dates. my charData looks like this.

```
var chartData = {
                labels: dates,
                datasets: [{
                        yAxisID: "funding",
                        label: "Credorax DK Funding",
                        data: [{
                                y: CredoraxDK[i].y,
                                x: CredoraxDK[i].x

                        }],
                        position: "left",
                    },
                    {
                        yAxisID: "release",
                        label: "Credorax DK Release",
                        data: [{
                                y: CredoraxDK[i].y2,
                                x: CredoraxDK[i].x

                        }],
                        position: "right",
                    },
```

When i try to do it like this, i only get the first object key out in the array. Is there any way i can iterate through the array with given keys ?

my new Chart looks like this

```
                var ctx = document.getElementById("likviditetChart").getContext("2d");
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "line",
                data: chartData,

                options: {
                    stacked: false,
                    responsive: true,
                    onHover: [],
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: "index",
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    max: 100000,
                                    min: 0,
                                },
                                type: "linear",
                                display: true,
                                title: "Funding",
                                id: "funding",
                                position: "left",

                            }, {
                                ticks: {
                                    max: 100000,
                                    min: 0,
                                },
                                type: "linear",
                                display: true,
                                title: "Release",
                                id: "release",
                                position: "right",
                            }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

[Picture of graph. As you can see there are only two points on the graph, and i have 6 objects in my array, but when i write chart data like this, chart.js only puts out the first object in the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcPML.png)

hope my problem can be solved somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you mean;

If you have created chartData, you can acces the dataset as follows:

```
chartData = {
    datasets: [{
              yAxisID: "funding",
              label: "Credorax DK Funding",
              data: [],
              position: "left",
        },
        {
              yAxisID: "release",
              label: "Credorax DK Release",
              data: [],
              position: "right",
        }
   ,//other config, etc...
  };

//init chart with this config
var ctx = document.getElementById("likviditetChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, chartData);

//itterate your data and add it to the datasets
for (var i = 0; i < CredoraxDK.length;i++){
    chartData.datasets[0].data.push({
                            y: CredoraxDK[i].y,
                            x: CredoraxDK[i].x});
    chartData.datasets[1].data.push({
                            y: CredoraxDK[i].y2,
                            x: CredoraxDK[i].x});
}

//update  new data.
chart.update();
```

So basically, you set up the chart config first, and add the chart-data to the data array later.

Don't forget to call the `chart.update();` function when you are done.

Comment: Just what i was looking, for thanks ;). i works perfect now.

Comment: @ThomasStaal: Appreciation is usually expressed by up-voting or even marking the answer as an answer :-)

Comment: Unfortunate that the OP is not accepting your answer. You have my vote.

Comment: Wheeee! :) Thanks